# How to tell bxslider to change the minimum number of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a hypothetical question , suppose i am using the plugin bxslider and at smaller widths i want to change the minimum no. of images, how do i do it? let me explain, see the below code:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 170,
  slideMargin: 10
});
```

Taken from **[HERE](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides')** , now suppose at a smaller width , i would like the minimum number of images to be say 2 , how to i do this ? , so say in jQuery i have a `resize` handler , something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

   if($(window).width() < 768) {
      // here is where i would like to change the min number of images
   }

});
```

So once again to repeat my question , how do i change the minimum no. of images in bxslider ?

**EDIT**:: one way i realise as i was typing this question was to call the `destroy()` function  on bxslider, like so:

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
slider.destroySlider();
```

And then maybe recall the plugin on the element, But i really want to know what other interesting solutions exit for this sort of a scenario. (I'am going to go try my solution and see if it works in the mean time ).

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link hope this may help

http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings